# ajax/PHP (Icecast) - How do I combine ajax and php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want add the value of #track-title in $currentsong ...

i want set the src of attr img.

is that possible? or any other idea?

```
<script>
function radioTitle() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://radio.example.com:8000/json.xsl',
    async: true,
    jsonpCallback: 'parseMusic',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
       $('#track-title').text(json['/radio']['title']); 

       //here i need help!!!
       $('img.image').attr({src: '<?PHP echo "/blablabla/".$currentsong.".jpg";?>'});
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){radioTitle();}, 0000);
  setInterval(function(){radioTitle();}, 5000);
});
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you already have the info you need in your JSON response or that you misunderstand how an AJAX call works. You need to extract the JSON response with $.parseJSON() method. This will give you an array/object which you can iterate over. Use that to get the tracks title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uhm...
the response of "http://radio.example.com:8000/json.xsl",...
must be contains a image url or image file path.
if the response has a image, json['/radio']['imageurl'] points the image url(or path), then

```
 $('img.image').attr({src: '<?=$image_dir_path?>/' + json['/radio']['imageurl']});
```